# Doctrine DQL Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, prepared-statement, dql

I'm getting the error `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` on this query.

I really don't see the problem, any ideas?

```
public function getByPartial($q, Company $company)
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->join('u.company',':company')
        ->where('u.firstName LIKE :q')
        ->orWhere('u.lastName LIKE :q')
        ->setParameters(array('company' => $company, 'q' => '%'.$q.'%'))
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

company can't be a parameter, you just have to specify an alias such as :

```
public function getByPartial($q, Company $company)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('c')
        ->join('u.company','c')
        ->where('u.firstName LIKE :q OR u.lastName LIKE :q')
        ->andWhere('c.id = :companyId')
        ->setParameters(array('companyId' => $company->getId(), 'q' => '%'.$q.'%'))
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the exact number of parameters.

```
public function getByPartial($q, Company $company)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->join('u.company','c')
        ->where('u.firstName LIKE :q1 OR u.lastName LIKE :q2')
        ->andWhere('c.id = :company_id')
        ->setParameters(array('company_id' => $company->getId(), 'q1' => '%'.$q.'%', 'q2' => '%'.$q.'%'))
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

**EDITED**
The join does not take any object params. [Documentation](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html?highlight=join)

Comment: Still getting the same error. When I remove the join part with company it seems to work?